# only string match with camelCase

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am trying to create regular expression which will match with function name in a given string and all matching element should be store in array, like I have below

`abcFunctionName=function()xyzFunction=function()`

and in result array we have

```
array[0]=abcFunctionName    array[1]=xyzFunction
```

How can it possible in javaScript, please suggest?

Comment: if the string format is fixed, regex is not required: `var names = 'abcFunctionName=function()xyzFunction=function()'.split('=function()').slice(0, -1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based code:

```
var s = 'abcFunctionName=function()xyzFunction=function()';
var arr = s.match(/(\w+)(?==function)/g);
//=> ["abcFunctionName", "xyzFunction"]
```

Comment: Anubhav, again stuck on this point "function abc()" and I want to extract "abc" only, please suggest regex for this, thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `/function +([^(]+)/` with matched group #1 as `abc`

Comment: thanks again but actually I don’t want function key word  in array only abc, so it means  key between “function” and “()” , we actually not able to track how can I extract right hand value with matching left side. Please suggest.

Comment: You need to take item at 1st position for that and ignore what you get at 0th position. So `var arr = s.match(/function +([^(]+)/); console.log(att[1]);`

Comment: Anubhav again disturbing you, actually I have some function to perform that is extracting some specified string only, I cannot pick it by index of array as I have lots of filters in array based on these Regex matched///////
I require only abc from “function abc()”, Is it possible to return abc only? second , We have some more as “var klm” How can I pick “klm” from that/////
I made some of them example you given but struggling for some above points if you can help that will be great.

Comment: Javascript regex doesn't have lookbehind therefore you have to get it from `arr[1]` as I have shown. Also I request you to create a new question with other `var` related problems so that you can get many more answers.